# How to achieve verifiable randomness on Polygon, Avalanche, Arbitrum, etc...?

Tags: chainlink, randomness

Chainlink VRF is only available on Ethereum and BSC so how does protocols on other chains achieve randomness?

Answer (score 0):

DIA uses the drand.love public randomness beacon, and updates its oracle with round number, randomness and signature. Anyone can access published random values via round ID and various EVMs.

https://docs.diadata.org/documentation/oracle-documentation/randomness-oracle